# PowerShell - Add-SPOSiteScript - addSPLookupFieldXml action not recognised

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-design, site-script

I would like to add some new tables to my SPO site through using PowerShell and a site script. One of the columns is a Lookup type. According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#addsplookupfieldxml), I should be able to use the action `addSPLookupFieldXml` to add this column. However, when I run the `Add-SPOSiteScript` command in PowerShell, I receive this error:

```
Add-SPOSiteScript : This action isn't recognized: addSPLookupFieldXml
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "Add Test List" -Content $site_script -Desc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-SPOSiteScript], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.AddSP
   OSiteScript
```

The relevant part of my site script contains:

```
      {
         "verb": "addSPLookupFieldXml",
         "schemaXml": "<Field Type=\"Lookup\" ID=\"{9265de7a-db84-4357-b975-f83c7a7d724a}\" DisplayName=\"Test Lookup Column\" Required=\"TRUE\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" Group=\"Test Group\" ShowField=\"ID\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"FALSE\" RelationshipDeleteBehavior=\"None\" StaticName=\"TestColumn\" Name=\"TestColumn\"></Field>",
         "targetListName": "OriginalTestList",
         "addToDefaultView": true
      }
```

I can create and modify lists with no issues if I exclude this action, but I require a Lookup column for my list. Does anyone have any advise?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint online PowerShell are you using? Try updating to latest version & see if it works.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I updated and when I check, the version is `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 16.0.21513.12000
Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 16.0.21513.0`
I tried running the site script again and get the same error